# How to add a custom button beside the list display in django admin panel? To edit the form from list display it self

Tags: python, django, django-models, model-view-controller, django-forms

> I have attached my admin panel screenshot
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWZ4K.png

Here is my admin.py code:

```
`from django.contrib import admin
        from .models import *
        from django.utils import *
        import csv
        from django.http import HttpResponse
        

        class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            search_fields = ('name',)
            list_display = ('name','price',)
        
        admin.site.register(Product,ProductAdmin)`
```

Comment: example an example of a field that can be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a button, I would suggest making the 'price' field editable.
Use the attribute list_editable = ('price',).

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    list_display = ('name','price',)

    list_editable = ('price',)
```

[image]